# Website Div Tags overlapping when viewed using Chromes Developer tools?

Tags: javascript, html, css, display

Im developing a website for my boss and have been noticing weird behavior, after looking closer i corrected my div tags.

Now when I examine my webPage it shows my imageGallery div borders Overlapping my content Div, It still displays most content properly but is confusing me greatly and i want to solve it before moving on.

http://2286bowmanroad.com/

ctrl+shift+i on chrome under elements if you highlight ImageGallery you will see it is also behind content but must be bellow.

Lots of Googling has been tried and trial and error with positioning and fixing div tags this is the only set of divs causing issue and i cant tell why.

I want my image gallery div to be completely bellow the content div but above the footer

Comment: Where is the ImageGallery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because you gave `float: left` to the class content. I am sure you gave it for some reason, but moment you remove it, it'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. I'm using the old code they provided to update it and currently reworking the css didn't notice that. Why would that cause this though?